# Is this error "Only Win32 target is supported" coming from wrong cc1plus?

Tags: debian, kali-linux, cross-compilation, 32bit, mingw

I am trying to cross compile [Hyperion](https://github.com/nullsecuritynet/tools/tree/master/binary/hyperion/release) for a 32-bit Windows on a 64-bit Debian linux, but I ran into a few problems in doing so.

First of all, in attempt to install a cross compiler, I installed mingw32 on linux. I am not sure if I installed the correct version or not since there were so much similar packages. Eventually, I locate and read a readme.txt and learn that i686-w64-mingw32-gcc is supposed to be the correct 32-bit Windows C compiler, but there were two versions of i686-w64-mingw32-gcc that might be what I am looking for: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc and i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32. So I chose to use i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32.

Next, it complaints about not being able to locate cc1plus. A locate of that file led me to /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/. I went ahead creating a soft link at /usr/bin to /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus.

Afterward, it complaints about missing windows.h. I locate it at /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/. After adding -I option to that path to CFLAGS, I got various strange errors. Among them is the one below:

> /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/_mingw.h:264:2: error: #error Only Win32
>   target is supported!

Now, I am stuck. I am not sure which step I did wrong. I suspect that it might be the wrong cc1plus I soft linked, but I don't know how to get the right version if that is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cc1plus` you linked is the normal C++ compiler's, not the Windows cross-compiler's. You should never need to fix GCC's internal components; the `cc1plus` error indicates something else is wrong.

In your case, you need to install [`mingw-w64`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/mingw-w64) (`apt-get install mingw-w64`). This will install a C and C++ cross-compiler for Windows and the appropriate header files and libraries. Then use `i686-w64-mingw32` as the target; `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` should work fine. (See the `README.Debian` in `/usr/share/doc/gcc-mingw-w64-base` for details of the `-win32` v. `-posix` stuff; the defaults should work fine for you.)

Comment: mingw-w64 is not found when using apt-get as I tried that before using the GUI Package manager. This is where I ran into problems of which packages I needed. I will try to remove the soft link to cc1plus to see if I can install the proper packages to fix that problem.

Comment: What version of Debian are you using?

Comment: If you can't install the `mingw-w64` package (which suggests there's something very wrong with your `apt` sources — the package is present in Debian 7 and 8), you can try installing `g++-mingw-w64-i686` (that's the 32-bit-only C++ cross-compiler).

Comment: Actually, I make a mistake. I should have said that I have Kali linux, a Debian-based linux, not Debian linux. Your suggestion for trying to install g++-mingw-w64-i686 makes me realized something as well. I was using the wrong compiler the whole time. I kept thinking that I need a C compiler, but in reality, the code was written in C++. After switching my compiler to i686-w64-mingw32-c++-win32, it works flawlessly. Thank you so much. I struggle with this problem for a very long time.